# Importing and testing a running service list in PowerShell v2.0

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have been working on a script to copy running services from a server and then export that list. After rebooting the server we compare the list to the services running on the rebooted server and restart any that don't start. Problem is that the servers are on version 2.0 and I don't have the option to update the servers. My Code looks like this:

```bsh
# To create the list of services in text file
(Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"}).Name |
    Out-File "C:\ListOfServices.txt"
# For testing add BlackJack as a service that doesn't exist 

#Restart-Computer -Force
```

```bsh
Write-Host "Starting required services " -ForegroundColor Cyan
$date = Get-Date -Format G 
Write-Host $date -ForegroundColor Cyan
# Services array needed to be started when the Server comes back up 
$ServiceNameArray = Get-Content -Path "C:\ListOfServices.txt"

foreach ($serviceName in $ServiceNameArray) {
    if (Get-Service $serviceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        if ((Get-Service $serviceName).Status -eq 'Running') {
            Write-Host "$serviceName found, and is running" -ForegroundColor Green
        } else {
            Write-Host "$serviceName found, but it is not running." -ForegroundColor Yellow

            Stop-Service -InputObject $serviceName
            Get-Service -InputObject $serviceName

            Start-Sleep 3

            Start-Service -InputObject $serviceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
            $services = $serviceName
            $maxRepeat = 20
            $status = "Stopped" # change to Stopped if you want to wait for services to start

            do {
                $count = (Get-Service $services | ? {$_.status -eq $status}).Count
                $maxRepeat--
                sleep -Milliseconds 1000
            } until ($count -eq 0 -or $maxRepeat -eq 0)

            Get-Service -InputObject $serviceName 
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "$serviceName not found" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
Write-Host "Starting required services has ended" -ForegroundColor Cyan
$date = Get-Date -Format G 
Write-Host $date -ForegroundColor Cyan 
Remove-Item "C:\ListOfServices.txt"
Write-Host "Removed Services text file" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Comment: Which part of the code isn't working in v2?

Comment: I'm looking at the If statement

Comment: if ((Get-Service $serviceName).Status -eq 'Running')

Comment: I can export the file and import it but the breakdown is when it looks at the status to see if it is running. I get a response that it is not installed. I can hard code the service names in and it works fine.